# Install Fixtures in Sylius - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, fixtures, icu, sylius

After having successfully installed and updated all vendors in my project folder for [Sylius](http://sylius.com/get-started) i tried running this code :

> app/console sylius:install --fixtures

I get this error :

> > PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor\
> >     symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale.php on line 51

Then i tried [all possible solutions given here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/32)

Installed intl extension in php (working successfully).Then ran this command

> php build-data.php 'your ICU version'

On running the above command i get this:

> 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   The command "svn" is not installed

I want to know if there is another workaround to this issue.
Please help and thanks in advance.

P.S. - No SVN runs on my system. And i'm using icu*46.dll

Anyone came across this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error relates to be PHP intl-extension. Make sure it is enabled and you have the LATEST version.

quick test:

```
<?php
    var_dump(extension_loaded('intl'));
```

Make sure your PHP folder is correctly registered in your %PATH% environment variable.

```
Control Panel - System - Advanced - ...
```

Without that, the ICU dlls are not loaded by PHP as Apache module - no error message is displayed, but the extension is not enabled.

Check aswell from **phpinfo()** ! not with ...

```
php -m
```

... or ( windows = findstr, linux/cygwin = grep )

```
php -i | findstr intl
```

check that the extension is enabled in your php.ini ( dont know WAMP's extenion path so adjust it please )

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

As i can see you are on Windows and using WAMP you will have to get a precompiled version of the extension.

The packages on http://windows.php.net/download/ all contain the php_intl.dll in the ext folder.

**Make sure that the ICU is compiled with the same version of MSVC that PHP is**.

You run into problems if the ICU was compiled with **VC10** and PHP was with **VC9**.

Although php -m and php -i detect the INTL it wouldn't show up in phpinfo().

Comment: I have looked far and wide, all i got to know was there is a mismatch in the icu*.dll files used in my wamp server files and those compiled by symfony2.2. Anyone??

Comment: know your icu version? A quick fix is to go into `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Component/Locale/Locale.php` and change

`const ICU_DATA_VERSION` to match your installed ICU version.

Comment: Yes..my icu installed icu version is 46. I tried changing the `const ICU_DATA_VERSION` to 46 but to no avail.

Comment: tried newer one from http://site.icu-project.org/download ? btw the versions contain a dot usually 46 is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks..i did try with 4.6 but still doesn't work. And on the link that u gave i'm unable to find icudll files compiled with VC9 for windows 32. What are my chances now??('exhausted')

Comment: hm quickly updating apache in wamp is not an option? i think you should be able to exchange apache in your wamp install with a new version easily :)

Comment: Sorry..i dint get you. But does that mean i will have to make a custom set of php and apache compiled with VC10? (cuz currently it is VC9)

Comment: why not get v10 versions of apache and php and copy over your current configuration. should not be too much of a hassle? whilst php can be found on the php download pages you can get a precompiled apache at http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Comment: Surely i'll do that.And this sums up that your first answer was the correct one..de facto **You run into problems if the ICU was compiled with VC10 and PHP was with VC9.**. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: glad i could help somehow - happy coding :)